# Обращение к экземпляру класса,возвращает значение true/false

Tags: c#

Есть класс:

```
public class DaateTime
{
    private DateTime data;

    public DaateTime()
    {
        data = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01);
    }
    public DaateTime(DateTime data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public DateTime Data
    {
        get
        {
            return data;
        }
        set
        {
            data = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Я создаю его экземпляр:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DaateTime da = new DaateTime(new DateTime(2000,01,01));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Далее от меня хотят следующее: обращение к экземпляру класса дает значение true, если установленная дата является началом года, иначе – false; Что-то я не понимаю, что мне нужно сделать, каким образом я должен обратиться к экземпляру, или просто через свойство бахнуть?

Comment: Почему не уточнить задание у того, кто его вам дал?

Comment: Вот и обращайтесь: `da.Data`. Создайте функцию, которая вернет true/false и в нее передавайте ваш `DaateTime`

Comment: @gil9red но тогда по логике я обращаюсь к свойству экземпляра класса

Comment: "обращение к экземпляру класса" - смысл этой фразы известен только Вам. Попробуйте его нам объяснить.

Comment: @Igor я же спросил потому что я сам не понимаю, как это сделать

Comment: @Valera Я спрашиваю не "как сделать", а "что сделать".

Comment: Нас всех очень интересует, что именно от вас ждали в решении. Будьте так добры, отпишитесь потом, когда сдадите задание.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В C# есть [операторы true и false](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/true-false-operators). Зачем и для чего они были введены - даже старые мудрецы уже не помнят. Но истинные джедаи таки могут поиметь с них гешефт.

Добавьте в свой класс операторы:

```
public static bool operator true(DaateTime dt) => dt.data.DayOfYear == 1;
public static bool operator false(DaateTime dt) => dt.data.DayOfYear != 1;
```

После чего обращение именно к экземпляру класса будет возвращать булево значение:

```
var dt = new DaateTime();
if (dt) ...
```

Comment: Феерическая жесть убивающая читабельность кода, надеюсь от автора ждали не этого. Однако как решение поставленной задачи - круто)

Comment: @yolosora - я узнал о существовании этих операторов когда-то давно на другом форуме: там школяр просил написать код с использованием перечисленных фич. Я так понимаю, это методичка учебных заведений - они пишутся раз и на века... Составитель где-то вычитал, что есть такие операторы, вписал задание с ними в методичку, теперь преподы тупо копируют.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class DaateTime
{
  ...

  public bool ToBoolean() 
  {
    return data.DayOfYear == 1;
  }
}

DaateTime da = new DaateTime(new DateTime(2000,01,01));
Console.WriteLine(da.ToBoolean());
```

---

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Может быть от вас хотели, чтобы вы научились пользоваться методами расширения ?

```
public static class DateTimeExt
{
    public static bool IsCoolDate(this DateTime date)
    {
        return date.DayOfYear == 1;
    }
}
```

использовать так:

```
var t = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01).IsCoolDate();
```